# showing 1 to 10 entries of 100 not showing in jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am facing two problems with the jquery JS.

1 . (I have my default display length in the show '10' entries to be defaulted to 10). So for the first 10 records my logic works fine. When I click on next button and navigate to the remaining paginated records and click on any data row, my logic is not working.

```
<table>
  <c: forEach items="${tdetails}" var="tdetail" varStatus="loop">
  <tr>
      <td>${loop.index+1}</td>
      <td><a tag name="det12" id="delhi" href="#" >${tdetail.empNumber}</a></td>
      <td>${tdetail.empName}</td>
      <td>${tdetail.empDate}</td>
      <td>${tdetail.empStatus}</td>
  </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
<form id="employeeform" action="./getEmployeeStatusDisplay" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" id="empNumber" name="empNumber" value="${tdetail.empNumber}">
</form>
```

2 . "Showing 1 to 10 of 100 entries" is not getting displayed. I am using the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#detailstable').dataTable({  
    "bFilter": false,  
    "bInfo": false,  
    "bAutoWidth": false,  
    "bSortClasses": false,  
    "displayLength":10,  
    "oLanguage": {  
        "sInfo": "Showing START to END of TOTAL entries",  
        "sZeroRecords": "No data to show" },  
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip'  
  });

  $('td a[name="det12"]').click(function(){
      alert("inside JS");
      id=$(this).text();
      alert(id);
      $('#empNumber').val(id);
      $.blockUI({ 
          message: $('#spinnerbox'), 
          css: { 
              margin:'0px auto' 
          } 
      }); 
      $("#spinner").show();
      $("#employeeform").submit();
  });
});
```

As you can see, when i click on the first column ${tdetail.empNumber} of the datatable which is href tag, it should invoke the 'det12' JS which results in displaying another form ('employeeform.jsp'). The problem is only for the first 10 datarows this logic is working fine, for the remaining 11 to 100 records this doesnt work.

Comment: Make a http://jsfiddle.net/ please?

Comment: Please clarify what "logic not working" means

Comment: Thank you all. Please see my edited post above. Kidnly let me know for any further information. As am a newbie to this website, finding little difficult to paste code snippets. Now i learnt it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesnt work because the `<td>` `click` function is resetted each time a new page is shown in the dataTable, and you only does `$('td a[name="det12"]').click(function(){` once (thats why it works with the first page, rows 1-10). One way to solve this is by setting the trigger each time the datatable is redrawn (that is, when the user clicks on another page) the callback function [`fnDrawCallback`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks) can be used for that :

```
$('#detailstable').dataTable({
   "bFilter": false,
   "bInfo": false,
   "bAutoWidth": false,
   "bSortClasses": false,
   "displayLength":10,
   "oLanguage": {
       "sInfo": "Showing START to END of TOTAL entries",
       "sZeroRecords": "No data to show" 
   },
   "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',

   fnDrawCallback : function() {
       $('td a[name="det12"]').click(function(){ 
          alert("inside JS"); 
          id=$(this).text(); 
          alert(id); 
          $('#empNumber').val(id); $.blockUI({ message: $('#spinnerbox'), css: { margin:'0px auto' } });    
          $("#spinner").show(); 
          $("#employeeform").submit(); 
       })
    }                                  
});
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/hf1zqpoz/** I cannot reproduce your setup entirely, but click through the pages, and click on records with the content "Trident".

Comment: Thanks a lot David. I tried fnDrawCallback() which you have explained. But some how it was also not working. Finally with my friends help i found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some thread (which may have been previously invoked not destroyed properly) would have been creating these kind of problems. So i tried the following in the script tag of my JSP file. Then it is working fine. Hope this helps someone who is facing similar issue like this.

```
$('#detailstable').dataTable({
   "bFilter": false,
   "bInfo": false,
   "bAutoWidth": false,
   "bSortClasses": false,
   "displayLength":10, 
   });
   var bindLinks = function(){
 $('td a[name="det12"]').click(function(){
   id=$(this).text();
   $('#empNumber').val(id);
   $("#employeeform").submit();
  });
 };
 $("#detailstable").bind("draw.dt", function(){
        bind();
      });
  });
```

Great forum. Thanks guys.